# Set the .htaccess path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is something I was curious about earlier.
Now I'm presuming this isn't possible, after my Google searches. But i'd be interested to find out for certain.

Is it possible to specify the .htaccess filepath/filename, either via Apache or PHP?

For example, If I wanted a htaccess file to be in `/config/.siteone`, instead of `/.htaccess`

Or will Apache *only* look for the latter?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Apache checks for an `.htaccess` file located within each directory so no, it isn't possible to change the path to an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: See [how directives are applied](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) on Apache's website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just being reading up on AccessFileNames, and wondering if these can be set via PHP.

Comment: See [`AccessFileName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#accessfilename). It's typically just the basename, but try configuring it to `config/.siteone` and tell us.